# Comparing a dictionary with a tuple as a key to a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples, compare

I'm having some issues figuring this problem out and was hoping to get some assistance. So I want to compare a list to a dictionary, take below as an example, the only output I want is "('value5', **287**, 'router2'): 'item, item'}" (I do not want ('value5', **200**, 'router2'): 'item, item'}

```
dict1 = {
('value1', 287, 'router1'): 'item, item', 
('value2', 287, 'router1'): 'item, item', 
('value3', 200, 'router2'): 'item, item', 
('value4', 200, 'router2'): 'item, item'
('value5', 200, 'router2'): 'item, item'
('value5', 287, 'router2'): 'item, item'
}

lst = [
['value1', 287, 'router1'], 
['value2', 287, 'router1'], 
['value3', 200, 'router2'], 
['value4', 200, 'router2']
['value5', 200, 'router2']
]
```

I've made a solution looking at them one by one and the below code does exactly that (I've only added for router_id 287). However, what I want to solve is, if another key + item is added to the dictionary, let's say "value6, 300" and "value7, 400" I shouldn't have to modify the def.

```
router_id = (287,200)

def find_missing_vrfs(librenms_VRF, polled_vrfs, router_id):
    data = []
    #all_vrfs = polled_vrfs
    
    
    for number in router_id:
        for values in librenms_VRF:      
            if values[1] == router_id[0]:
                data.append(values[0])
                
    polled_vrfs = {k: polled_vrfs[k] for k,v in polled_vrfs.items() if k[1] == router_id[0]}
    all_vrfs = polled_vrfs
    polled_vrfs = {k: polled_vrfs[k] for k,v in polled_vrfs.items() if k[0] in data and set(data)}
    missing_vrfs = set(polled_vrfs.items()) ^ set(all_vrfs.items())
    print(missing_vrfs)

find_missing_vrfs(lst, dict1, router_id)
```

What I'm thinking is that I should be able to compare the key directly to the list as they contain the values that should be added but failing to do so, anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was fairly simple, just had to do the comparison list to list

```
polled_vrfs = {k: polled_vrfs[k] for k,v in polled_vrfs.items() if list(k) in librenms_VRF}
```